# Joomla - offline page - php send mail not working

Tags: php, email, joomla, send

I have made an offline page which should allow users to submit their email address and mail it to me here is the code

```
    <form action="/templates/jp-revo/send_contact.php" method="post">
<fieldset class="input">
    <div id="form-login-username">

        <input name="email" id="customer_mail" type="text" class="inputbox"  size="18" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button login" value="Okay" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

and here is send_contact.php

```
    <?php

    // Contact subject
    $subject ="test"; 

    // Details        
    $message="hello";

    // Mail of sender
    $mail_from="$customer_mail"; 
    $header="To : Ben <$mail_from>";
    // Enter your email address
    $to ='ben@imne.co.uk';
    $send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    // Check, if message sent to your email 
    // display message "We've recived your information"
    if($send_contact){
    echo "We've recived your contact information";
    }
    else {
    echo "ERROR";
    }
    ?>
```

The site is http://smoothprint.co.uk

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

When you submit it goes to this page http://smoothprint.co.uk/templates/jp-revo/send_contact.php

Comment: What *is* going wrong?

Comment: sends you to this page http://smoothprint.co.uk/templates/jp-revo/send_contact.php

Comment: But what is wrong with that? Sounds like it's doing what you're telling it to do

Comment: its not sending the email? just keeps going to the error page

Comment: Why not trying using Joomla's built in mailing function?

Comment: If I used Joomla's built in mailing function would I just change the send_contact.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-are you using joomla?
if yes it's better using joomla functions to send emails see [this link](http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions)

-are your server configuration is ok for sending emails?

-change `$header="To : Ben <$mail_from>";` to `$header="FROM: Ben <$mail_from>";`

-in code `$mail_from="$customer_mail";` you should first get $customer_mail from post:

```
$customer_mail = $_POST['email'];

//or joomla way:
$customer_mail = JRequest::getvar('email')
```

Comment: `$_POST` >> not Joomla coding standards .... `JRequest` >> deprecated. Also missing a semi colon